# Use a switch statement to assign months to an array key value PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to print the month name followed by the monthly expense for the corresponding array value (1=jan, 2=feb...ect). I have gotten pretty far and can print "Month [1] $2997.10" for example, but can't figure out how to print it in the format "Jan $2997.10". I know it's something simple I'm missing, but I've tried everything I can think of and only get error messages. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
     $monthly_expense = array(    '1' => 2997.10,
                              '2' => 921.00,
                              '3' => 371.99,
                              '4' => 1928.00,
                              '5' => 1206.00,
                              '6' => 10190.33,
                              '7' => 8390.35,
                              '8' => 3009.93,
                              '9' => 4803.30,
                              '10'=> 1212.30,
                              '11'=> 225.90,
                              '12'=> 594.65
                              );

 //Your program starts here!
switch ($monthly_expense) {
case 1:
    $month = 'Jan';
    break;
case 2:
    $month = 'Feb';
    break;

case 3:
    $month = 'Mar';
    break;
case 4:
    $month = 'Apr';
    break;
case 5:
    $month = 'May';
    break;
case 6:
    $month = 'Jun';
    break;
case 7:
    $month = 'Jul';
    break;
case 8:
    $month = 'Aug';
    break;
case 9:
    $month = 'Sep';
    break;
case 10:
    $month = 'Oct';
    break;
case 11:
    $month = 'Nov';
    break;
case 12:
    $month = 'Dec';
    break;
default:
    $month = 'Not a valid month!';

    break;
}

for ($count = 1; $count < sizeof($monthly_expense)+1; $count++)
     printf ("Month [%d]: $%.2f\n", $monthly_expense[$count]);


 //Compute the total of all salaries
 $totalExpense = 0.0;

 foreach ($monthly_expense as $value)
     $totalExpense += $value;

 printf ("The total company expenses for the year is $%.2f.\n", $totalExpense);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more efficient to use an array which contains every month like this:

```
$months = array(1 => 'Jan.', 2 => 'Feb.', 3 => 'Mar.', 4 => 'Apr.', 5 => 'May', 6 => 'Jun.', 7 => 'Jul.', 8 => 'Aug.', 9 => 'Sep.', 10 => 'Oct.', 11 => 'Nov.', 12 => 'Dec.', 13=>'Total');

for ($count = 1; $count < sizeof($monthly_expense)+1; $count++)
    printf("%s $%.2f <br>", $months[$count], $monthly_expense[$count]);
```

Comment: Saved me from typing the array... gracias amoeba

Answer (score 0):

You could add another array for the names of the months (because that `switch` statement looks so bad):

```
 $months = array(
     'undefined', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'
  );
```

and then:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($monthly_expense); $i++) {
   printf ("Month [%s]: $%.2f\n", $months[$i], $monthly_expense[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need an array of months anyway, just use [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [mktime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to get the month from the key in `$monthly_expense` array:

```
foreach( $monthly_expense as $month => $value ) {
    printf( "Month [%s]: $%.2f\n", date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1) ), $value );
}
```